# Magento 2 Add title in the middle of the checkout form

Tags: magento, knockout.js, magento2

I'm trying to add a simple title to the middle of the checkout form in magento. I've completed tutorials on knockout js, but i'm quite new to it, so magento converting the knockout module configuration to xml is still confusing.

I have chased down the location in the `checkout_index_index.xml` file to be this node

```
<item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">additional-fieldsets</item>
   <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
   <!-- The following items override configuration of corresponding address attributes -->
   <item name="region" xsi:type="array">
      <!-- Make region attribute invisible on frontend. Corresponding input element is created by region_id field -->
      <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
   </item>
   <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/region</item>
      <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
          <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
          <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.region</item>
      </item>
      <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
      </item>
      <!-- Value of region_id field is filtered by the value of county_id attribute -->
      <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="target" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id]]></item>
          <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
      </item>
   </item>
   <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
      <!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
      <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code</item>
      <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
      </item>
   </item>
   <item name="company" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">0</item>
       </item>
   </item>
   <item name="fax" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">0</item>
       </item>
   </item>
   <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">115</item>
   </item>
   <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="description" xsi:type="string" translate="true">For delivery questions.</item>
        </item>
      </item>
   </item>
</item>
```

In the knockout tutorials i've done, when creating children components, the template name was still specified, but in this xml, I can't seem to make sense of the child elements, their templates and where to go to edit them/what files to override!

I basically just want to add a title into this part of my form

[image]

What is the best way to look at a xml file like this and "follow the breadcrumbs" to find the template file I need to edit, because its really confusing me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you want to add label above textbox right?

Comment: Yes, but I more so want to know how to figure out where the file is, as I can't seem to make sense of where to find with the way magento uses knockout js!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add the fields label as for billing address and shipping address fields, you can do via theme transaction if you have made a custom theme as per your language.

If you have a custom or third party theme:

You might find a CSV file there. If you have kept locale as English(United States) which is a default one, there will be a file named en_US.csv

```
app\design\frontend\Magento\Themename\i18n
```

Without theme:

```
Copy locale's csv file from /vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n folder to app/code/Magento/module-checkout/i18n directory.
```

Exapmle:

```
"First Name","Customer First Name"
"Last Name","Customer Last Name"
```

Comment: Please can you elaborate? This seems to be an answer for changing the placeholder in the input, rather than adding a label/header over a section of inputs. Thanks

Comment: <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
 
UI text strings are the text elements in the Magento Admin, including field names, instructions, notifications, and table and grid labels. When localizing Magento, you replace these strings with translation dictionary content.